# Is there a functionality like Ctrl + D in Sublime for Intellij Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea, sublimetext2

In Sublime Text I used to select some text (say a variable name) and I would just type Ctrl + D to get the rest of the occurrences of the same text.

Is there a functionality like that in Intellij Idea IDE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select All Occurrences (Ctrl-Cmd-G on Mac OS X is already available,   Windows hotkey Ctrl+Alt+Shift+J will be available from the next EAP – use double shift | Select All Occurrences action for now)